# How WebSphere manages startup order of EJB jars?

Tags: startup, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

When an ear would contain two ejb modules modulea.jar and moduleb.jar. And modulea.jar contains an @Startup ejbX, that calls another ejbY, which is not an @Startup ejb, from moduleb.jar during the startup of the bean X it is required that moduleb.jar is started first as otherwise the app server is not able to inject X into Y. But how to ensure that moduleb.jar is started first?

Currently I have this problem in WebSphere, but I can't seem to find a way to enforce an order. Is there something in the spec to manage order?

Or maybe WebSphere specific (rather not have vendor lock in though). Maybe it is a poor design to have a startup ejb and an ejb that is used by it in different modules, some insight about that is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to configure it via `Starting weight` in the module configuration (`Enterprise Applications > YourApplication > Manage Modules > ejbmoduleb.jar`)

> **Starting weight**
>
> Specifies the order in which modules are started when the server
>   starts. The module with the lowest starting weight is started first.

If you need order dependency among whole applications, you set `Startup order` in the  `Startup behavior` application configuration (`Enterprise Applications > YourApplication > Startup behavior`)

> **Startup order**
>
> Specifies the order in which applications are started when the server
>   starts. The startup order is like a starting weight. The application
>   with the lowest starting weight is started first.

If you plan to have `application.xml` deployment descriptor add the following entry to the descriptor and provide modules in the correct order.

```
<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
```

See also:

- [EJB module settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/uejb_remod.html?lang=en)
- [Application startup behavior](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/urun_rapp_startup_behavior.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks @Gas very clear and complete solution. It works now. Also found a work-around by first deploying the ear with only the missing EJB jar in it. Afterwards the full ear worked.