# ServletContextListener execution order for different wars

Tags: servlets, war, servletcontextlistener

Is it possible to control order of ServletContextListener execution in different wars?

Suppose there are 3 separate, independent modules A, B, and C in a web service. They can be initialized in any order, and there is no consequences. However, if an optional module D is present, it needs to be initialized first and may impact other modules. Is this configuration possible through Spring? Only thing that comes to mind is having a global ServletContextListener that polls if an init class for every module exists on class path but that solution seems pretty messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing the startup of applications can be done when they all WAR's are bundled in EAR. It can done by adding `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>` in `application.xmkl`.

If all WAR's are independent then there is no standard way of doing it. But, there are container specific features that allow you to do that.

**References:**

- [WebsphereManages Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068311/how-websphere-manages-startup-order-of-ejb-jars)
- [Tomcat Startup ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793891/tomcat-starting-webapps-in-a-specific-order)

If you want to define dependency between the servlet's of an application. 
You can define `Absolute ordering in web.xml` or `relative ordering in web-fragment.xml`.

**Here is how absolute ordering works:**

```
<web-app>
...
    <absolute-ordering>
      <name>A</name>
      <others/>
      <name>B</name>
    <absolute-ordering>
</web-app>
```

**If there is no absolute ordering in web.xml**, the container will look for relative ordering in web-fragment.xml. It looks something like this:

```
<ordering>
    <before>
    <others />
    </before>
</ordering>
```

Comment: I have not had time to research this very much further, but I think web-fragment.xml requires all modules to be added to some super war. Please do correct me if Im wrong. What Im trying to accomplish is deploying 4 separate wars that are not explicitly aware of each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can define ordering in web-fragment.xml or web.xml. refer the below link to understand more. https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment